# Random integer inside tensorflow function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want get random integers to generate a synthetic tensorflow dataset with a vanilla python function. If I use numpy, I only get single constant number for all the iterations in dataset. When I use tensorflow functions, I get back a tensor that my function won't accept and I can't seem to be able to turn it into a normal python integer that I can use as input for a function. What am I doing wrong?

```
@tf.function
def number(_):
    #not working
    x,y = np.random.randint(2,100,size=2)
    #x,y = tf.random.uniform((2,0),minval=0,maxval=0,dtype=tf.int32)#.numpy() also not working
    #x = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=1, maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32)
    #x,y = tf.experimental.numpy.random.randint(2,100)
    string = f'Image with {x} cats and {x+y} dogs'
    return(string)

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(range(10)))
dataset = dataset.map(number)
for label in dataset.take(5):
    print(label)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(b'Image with 21 cats and 59 dogs', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'Image with 21 cats and 59 dogs', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'Image with 21 cats and 59 dogs', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'Image with 21 cats and 59 dogs', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'Image with 21 cats and 59 dogs', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you want basically?

Comment: In the output I have with numpy, you can see I don't get random numbers. I'd like to get a different random number each time the function is mapped to the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def number(_):
    noise = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=1, maxval=20)
    return int(noise)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(range(10)))
dataset = dataset.map(number)
for label in dataset.take(5):
    print(label.numpy())

11
7
3
19
8
```

Comment: Thanks did not know you could just change it into an int like that. I also found tf.py_function in the meantime. I'll try out both approaches